# Can't open my disk .

Tags: disk

I had windows & Kali linux (dual boot)
then I took off Kali linux Parition so I delete it but I Made a mistake ... and PC won't boot "Rescue grub error" or something ...

but I installed Ubuntu & removed Windows and all . 
All is running fine but I just can't open one of my disks , this is the error :

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/imad/Disque local: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/imad/Disque local"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Thank you